# Jenkins auto created user account, how to login/change password?

Tags: security, tomcat, ubuntu, version-control, jenkins

I've setup Jenkins, and it's working well.  It uses the Perforce plugin as the SCM, and builds automatically upon a checkin.  My issue is that when a user makes a commit to the tree it auto creates a user account on the system, but no password is set, and the user cannot login.

The system is secured on a intranet, and I have set Jenkins to use "Jenkins own user database" and "Logged in users can do anything".  Problem is I can't find any way for someone to log in once they have made a commit, there username is shown in the list of auto-created accounts, but no password is ever sent. Is there a default password, or a way to reset?

The system is running on Ubuntu 12 with Tomcat7 serving the Jenkins front end.

Comment: For people who wonder what SCM is, it's Source Control Management. ;)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Users created by SCM are not "full" users. They are created for purposes of showing SCM changes and receiving e-mails. Therefore they need to sign up (using 'Sign Up' icon that appears to the left of of 'log in' icon in the upper right corner) and provide their password. It is advisable for the username to match the SCM name.

Alternatively, a user with a "full" account can go to `http://<jenkins-server>/people/` -> click on username -> click on Configure link to the left, and configure the user (I'm not 100% sure if this will work, though, try it).

Comment: Using the "sign up" option doesn't work; it gives a "User name is already taken" error.  (v1.466.2)

Comment: After adding the user with the second option, you need to go into "Manage Jenkins", "Configure System", under "Authorization", and then manually add them to the system and give them appropriate permissions.

Comment: @Bryan Larsen: I did not find "Authorization" section under "Configure System". Please guide me if I had done wrong.

Comment: @malenkiy_scot: The way you mentioned to configure user supported only to edit user Name. It doesn't support to edit user id. User id can be changed as : Go to "users" folder under jenkins home --> Rename "null" folder to your desired name --> Restart jenkins

Comment: @Ripon Al Wasim, We've got matrix based security turned on.  Not sure if that helps, but it might be a hint.

Comment: Going to /people/ and clicking configure does give you the opportunity to modify a user's password as well as some other properties of that user.  However, configuring permissions for these users must be done in Manage Jenkins -> Configure Global Security.  Click Matrix-Based Security and you can assign privileges users.

Answer (score 22):

With version 1.517, signing up didn't work and gave the "User name is already taken" error.

However you can go to to `http://<jenkins-server>/user/<autogenerated username>/configure` and set a password for the SCM user, which converts them into a full Jenkins user.

Comment: Makes me wonder why there is no link to the `/configure` page on the parent (user) page. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

- Go to `Manage Jenkins -> scroll down
- click on "Manage User" -> see userId -> click on setting symbol right side of user id(admin)->change the password field->click on save.
- Now you can login with new credentials

Comment: logged in as admin and there is no "Manage User" on the Manage Jenkins page :/